# How can I sort by highest when I have an array and there are objects of prices?

Tags: javascript

There is a function where I can sort maybe prices from highest to low or from low to high. Here is an example of the function

```
myarray.sort((a,b) => b.age - a.age)
```

But how can I sort when I have some objects in my array and in there is an array of objects and this prices I have to sort.

Here in durationcontract is the array and there are prices

Array:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
        {
            duration: '12',
            price: '24' 
        }, 
        {
            duration: '24',
            price: '800' 
        }, 
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
        {
            duration: '12',
            price: '60' 
        }, 
        {
            duration: '24',
            price: '120' 
        }, 
    ],
]
```

I have to sort all items in the array by the highest or lowest price in durationcontract.

I am struggling and hope anyone can help me

expected Output:

```
 [
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Seat',
    durationcontract: [
        {
            duration: '12',
            price: '24' 
        }, 
        {
            duration: '24',
            price: '1200' 
        }, 
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
        {
            duration: '12',
            price: '24' 
        }, 
        {
            duration: '24',
            price: '800' 
        }, 
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
        {
            duration: '12',
            price: '60' 
        }, 
        {
            duration: '24',
            price: '120' 
        }, 
    ],
]
```

Comment: Loop over the `arr` array and sort each `durationcontract` property?

Comment: Can you show an example of what your desired output would look like?

Comment: @DBS yes I edited my code. I want to sort my cars where the price is the highest from all cars in my array in durationcontract. So you can see in durationContract price is 1200 value so it should be the first car then because the price is the highest from all in the array of cars

Comment: Can you post the correct question array, as the output seems to be different

Comment: The only difference I'm seeing between the input and the expected output is that a new array element is created.  Where does that come from, and how is that related to sorting?

Comment: Do you just care about `price` or are you aiming to multiply it by `duration`? As one will give you highest/lowest price every (whatever unit your duration represents) and the other will give you the total price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you're using javascript.
you can map through the array and sort by highest price, then lowest:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
      { duration: '12', price: '24' },
      { duration: '24', price: '800' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
      { duration: '12', price: '60' },
      { duration: '24', price: '120' },
    ],
  },
];

// Sort the array by highest price in durationcontract, then by lowest
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const highestPriceA = Math.max(...a.durationcontract.map(item => parseFloat(item.price)));
  const highestPriceB = Math.max(...b.durationcontract.map(item => parseFloat(item.price)));

  if (highestPriceA !== highestPriceB) {
    return highestPriceB - highestPriceA;
  } else {
    const lowestPriceA = Math.min(...a.durationcontract.map(item => parseFloat(item.price)));
    const lowestPriceB = Math.min(...b.durationcontract.map(item => parseFloat(item.price)));
    return lowestPriceA - lowestPriceB;
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array::reduce()` to get min and max price:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
      { duration: '12', price: '24' },
      { duration: '24', price: '800' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
      { duration: '12', price: '60' },
      { duration: '24', price: '120' },
    ],
  },
];

const minmax = a => a.durationcontract.reduce((r, {price}) => 
  (r.min > price && (r.min = price), r.max < price && (r.max = price), r), 
{min:Infinity, max:-Infinity});

arr.sort((a, b) => (a = minmax(a), b = minmax(b), b.max - a.max || a.min - b.min));

console.log(arr);
```

```
` Chrome/123
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                n=2      |      n=20       |     n=200      |     n=2000    
Alexander   1.00x x1m 124 | 1.00x x100k 407 | 1.00x x10k 612 | 1.00x  x1k 652
Meloudi     1.48x x1m 184 | 2.70x  x10k 110 | 2.89x  x1k 177 | 2.91x x100 190
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const $chunk = [
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
      { duration: '12', price: '24' },
      { duration: '24', price: '800' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Mercedes-Benz C63s AMG',
    durationcontract: [
      { duration: '12', price: '60' },
      { duration: '24', price: '120' },
    ],
  },
];
const $input = [];
const arr = $input;

// @benchmark Meloudi
arr.toSorted((a, b) => {
  const highestPriceA = Math.max(...a.durationcontract.map(item => parseFloat(item.price)));
  const highestPriceB = Math.max(...b.durationcontract.map(item => parseFloat(item.price)));

  if (highestPriceA !== highestPriceB) {
    return highestPriceB - highestPriceA;
  } else {
    const lowestPriceA = Math.min(...a.durationcontract.map(item => parseFloat(item.price)));
    const lowestPriceB = Math.min(...b.durationcontract.map(item => parseFloat(item.price)));
    return lowestPriceA - lowestPriceB;
  }
});

// @benchmark Alexander

const minmax = a => a.durationcontract.reduce((r, {price}) => 
  (r.min > price && (r.min = price), r.max < price && (r.max = price), r), 
{min:Infinity, max:-Infinity});

arr.toSorted((a, b) => (a = minmax(a), b = minmax(b), b.max - a.max || a.min - b.min));

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));
```